# How can I store and retrieve data from a checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, checkboxlist

SQL Tables

### Listing

ID, Title.....

### ListingType

ID, Name

### ListingMatrix

ListingID, ListingTypeID

Basically a listing can be more than 1 type and I want that to be able to be shown using the ListingMatrix table. However, I'm having a lot of issues populating the checkboxlist because I have it being sorted by Title to keep it user friendly. I'm using VB.Net, LINQ and MS SQL.

```
Dim readListingMatrix = (From ListingCategories In db.ListingTypeMatrixes _
                         Where ListingCategories.ListingID = ListingID)

For Each row In readListingMatrix
     CheckBoxListListingCategories.Items(row.ListingTypeID - 1).Selected = True
Next
```

My issue is storing the checklistbox and editing it. Storing I think I could hack, but editing it is becoming a pain since I can't get the checkboxlist to check the correct boxes since their location changes due to the ORDER BY in my SQL Statement that populates the list.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  This question is unclear.

Comment: I'll explain better in the main area.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean.  Are you trying to check each box in the list that corresponds to a listing type from your listing matrix selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the value field of your checkboxes is filled with a ListingTypeID, do this:

```
Dim readListingMatrix = (From ListingCategories In db.ListingTypeMatrixes _
                         Where ListingCategories.ListingID = ListingID)

For Each row In readListingMatrix
    CheckBoxListListingCategories.Items.FindByValue(row.ListingTypeID).Selected = True
Next
```

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe how quick and easy you made it. Thank you so much!